# Update document in C# driver v2 migrate from Driver v1

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

My code using C# Mongo Driver Version1 `Repository`

```
        /// <summary>
        ///  Generic update method to update record on the basis of id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queryExpression"></param>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public void Update(Expression<Func<T, string>> queryExpression, string id, T entity)
        {
           var query = Query<T>.EQ(queryExpression, id);
           _collection.Update(query, Update<T>.Replace(entity)); 
        }
```

And I change the code to C# driver version 2

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Generic update method to update record on the basis of id


     /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryExpression"></param>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    public void Update(Expression<Func<T, string>> queryExpression, string id, T entity)
    {
       // var query = Query<T>.EQ(queryExpression, id);
        //_collection.Update(query, Update<T>.Replace(entity));


        var query = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(queryExpression, id);
        var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(queryExpression, id);
        _collection.UpdateOneAsync(query, update); ;

    }
```

I called by using (`controller`):

```
 public void Update(PostModel post)
        {
            _postRepo.Posts.Update(s => s.Id, post.Id, post);
        }
```

I did not get the document update.Do you know  what is the problem with my migration code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call an asynchronous method without `await` with `_collection.UpdateOneAsync(query, update);` which is not the root cause of your problem but you have no proper exception handling in this case.
Either `await` it or use the corresponding synchronous version [UpdateOne](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_UpdateOne.htm)

---

You probably also rather want to use [ReplaceOne](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_ReplaceOne.htm) as your initial version with the V1 driver also did a whole document replacement. The following should fit your needs (not tested though)

```
...
var query = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(queryExpression, id);
_collection.ReplaceOne(query, entity);
...
```

Comment: Can I use async .. await +  asynchronous method ? mix together?